# No backing instance variables in subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I have a class that subclass from `NSObject` - `Rectangle`, and it subclass - `Square`.

In Rectangle.h i have properties:

```
@property int height, width;
```

Im implementation file i manually declare backing variables:

```
@implementation Rectangle
{
    int _width;
    int _height;
}
```

My question is: in my subclass Square that inherit directly from `Rectangle` - `@interface Square : Rectangle`, i want to use variables declared in superclass. However, i can't see them through `_width` or `_height`, but only calling getter method - `self.width` or `[self setWidth:x]` accordingly.

Yes, there is no problem using getter method, but why i can't use backing variables that are synthesised (in my case declared manually)? Is that somehow protected even from child class?

Comment: off-topic: Square subclassing Rectangle violates [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to be able to have your subclasses access variable directly (similar to public or protected in C++), you can declare them in the interface block:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSInteger _asdf;
}
```

Before the Objective-C non-fragile instance variables enhancement, the ability to declare instance variables was only available in the @interface block, and those variables were available everywhere.  It was possible to lock down the variables with the @private directive as well.

So, to answer your question: Declaring variables in the @interface block will allow you to access them directly, but I would exercise caution as the language is much better now that it is possible to hide implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

You're only declaring them in the header file. As far as your subclass is concerned, that header file represents its parent's interface. Officially, it doesn't know about the private instance variables, only the public properties.

Comment: yes, but it knows about methods implementation in .m file, but not backing variables.. kind of confusing to me

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are private and therefore can be removed/renamed which would break subclasses. Even though they are synthesized backing variables you still don't know what the exact implementation is.

You can create a seperate header and/or use `@private` if you really need to access them in a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ivars that you create in your superclass in your subclass, then declare those ivars in your superclass's .h file (instead of properties). Also, you shouldn't "manually declare" the backing instance variables in your .m file since you get those automatically.

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject {
    int height;
    int width;
}
```